# Библиотека Requests-HTML, не могу вытащить все ссылки

Tags: python, requests, requests-html

пытаюсь спарсить авито.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession


session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://www.avito.ru/rossiya/vodnyy_transport/katera_i_yahty?p=1')

link =r.html.find('.item-description-title-link')

print(link)
```

Не могу достать ссылки. Не понимаю куда надо вписать href

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код возвращает список элементов `a`. Нужно обойти список и достать из каждого элемента атрибут `href`. Можно сделать так:

```
links = [link.attrs['href'] for link in r.html.find('.item-description-title-link')]

print(links)
```

Это то же самое, что:

```
links = []

for link in r.html.find('.item-description-title-link'):
    links.append(link.attrs['href'])

print(links)
```

Результат:

```
['/novorossiysk/vodnyy_transport/sea_ray_325_sundanser_1194899456', '/anapa/vodnyy_transport/rinker_fiesta_vee_242_1291352353', '/volgograd/vodnyy_transport/buksir_rbt_proekt_378_1506970496', ...]
```

Comment: Спасибо большое